# SslStream AuthenticateAsServer with optional ClientCertificate

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, sslstream

Considering the [*SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145065%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, the second parameter *clientCertificateRequired*:

If it is set to true, a client certificate is required. It will throw an exception if not. The client certificate will be available in the property *RemoteCertificate*.

When set to false, no client certificate is required, the property *RemoteCertificate* shall always be null. Even if one is provided by the client.

What I like to accomplish is to **let the client decide** whether it will or will not provide a certificate. But, if they do provide one, I like to know it on the server.

I have tried to first set the variable to true, if this fails, fallback to not require the certificat. However, this result in an "Already Authenticated Exception".

```
try{
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(x509certificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
}catch(Exception ex){
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(x509certificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly believe this is a documentation flaw.

Actually the parameter `clientCertificateRequired` will control whether client certificates are **not ignored**. This means:

`clientCertificateRequired = false` will ignore any client certificate on the server side. No certificate is checked for existence nor validity.

`clientCertificateRequired = true` will respect any sent client certificate on the server side. If a client certificate is missing the validation callback is called with `SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` which results in the exception you catch, when using the default implementation.

So in your case: Set `clientCertificateRequired` to `true` and implement a custom validation callback, like this:

```
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient()
var networkStream = client.GetStream()

var sslStream = new SslStream(
    networkStream,
    false,
    (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
    {
        if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (errors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)
        {
            // seems to be okay for you
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    },
    (sender, host, certificates, certificate, issuers) => x509certificate
);

sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(x509certificate, true, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

Comment: Just to add.  In TLS/SSL, if the server wants the client to provide a certificate, the server has to ask the client.  The client cannot provide a client certificate if the server didn't ask for one.  Setting `AuthenticateAsServer(clientCertificateRequired = true)` causes the server to ask for a client certificate.  Note also that the server-side `ValidateRemoteCertificate` may be called regardless of the setting of `clientCertificateRequired`, so checking for `SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable` and determining if that is acceptable to your server is the right way to do this.